# Windows 10 Beacon BackgroundTask

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, ibeacon, background-task

currently I'm working on an Beacon-App for Windows 10 phones. As a starting point I choosed Dan Ardeleans "Beacons.Universal" library at github (https://github.com/danardelean/Beacons.Universal). The backgroundtask works pretty well as long as I start the App directly from visual studio 2015 on my Nokia Lumia 925. Whenever I tap the App-Icon on the phone (without visual studio) the backgroundtask seems not working.

Thanks for helping me
Florian